# index number by vertices? in animation nodes.. is it possible?

Tags: animation-nodes

any way to give at this node a not unique index?

[image: ani-node index]

I mean.. can't figure out how to assign to It more than a value.. I'd like to align group's objects to vertexes of a grid. It actually works if using a instancer but this duplicate an object many times... not a group of individual objects.

[image: ANI-NODE FROM A GRID]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the index was not necessary, solved by adding an object list I/O to the loop node :)

[image: solved by object list]